# How do I setup a Nutch Crawler on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, nutch

I don't seem to find a credible instruction manual or guide online, can someone please guide me through the setup for a Nutch crawler on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any particular error? Can you provide more details about what you've already done. Usually on OS X is just a matter of installing the JRE/JDK from Oracle and exporting the right `JAVA_HOME` variable in your bash/zsh terminal. What is the output of the command `java -version` in your terminal?

Comment: This is the output of the command :                                                                     java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode). I followed the instructions provided on this website https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial but it did not seem to work

Comment: But does the `bin/crawl` script throws any errors? Are you not seeing any content on Solr? Do the logs have any errors? We need more info to figure what's wrong.

Comment: I figured it out my Java_Home was not set correctly. It works now. Thanks